# What are the most compatible special characters for login/passwords?

Tags: passwords, login, security-policy

As you would know, most password policy for apps and services require to set a password including a special character.

When setting a password for SSO/LDAP, password has to be compatible with all apps that use LDAP acccounts.

During last years I have found problems due this special characters, sometimes symbols have to be escaped at scripts.

For example @ symbol at username  can produce problems because some interfaces or cli apps expect a domain/urls after @.

From your experience which symbols are recommended in order to use as plain text and avoid escaping?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend avoiding & $ and @

However you can use # ! ~  ( ) _ from the number row

and the following from the three rows below : ; < > { } [ ]

Comment: While these do tend to be commonly accepted special characters, for some applications they are still not accepted.

Comment: I went through something from reddit and it says & is one of the least used one https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/2vfgvh/most_frequentlyused_special_characters_in_10/

Answer (score 0):

This will depend entirely on the applications your SSO system needs to work with.

*Our experience is not the same as yours. Your needs are unique to you due to the set of applications you wish to use SSO to authenticate being unique to you.*

The correct way to solve this problem FOR YOU is to look at the password requirements for the applications you are linking in this scheme and find the characters that are allowed by all of them, and then set the rules on your systems to only accept those characters.

Comment: that is the main problem, that sometimes you can't forecast which apps will be integrated/chosen. A standard would be the best but unfortunately it doesn't exist. So, at least I would like to decide policies based in best practices from users experience or from statistics of password policy at services.

Comment: I am not aware of any such statistical analysis, though, if it existed in a publicly published form, it could be found via a search of the internet.